# ¿Por qué tengo un error al validar el formulario sobre un campo que no tengo?

Tags: python, django

Tengo un formulario de registro con 3 campos, email, username y contraseña, pero cuando lo valido con

```
if form.is_valid()
```

Me devuelve false, y al sacar por pantalla `form.errors`
Esto es lo que obtengo

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>password1<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>password2<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

Pero sorprendentemente no tengo ninguno de estos campos, este es mi formulario:

```
<form action="{% url 'signup' %}" class="nk-form text-white" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="row vertical-gap">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        Usa email y contraseña:

                        <div class="nk-gap"></div>
                        {{signupForm.email}}

                        <div class="nk-gap"></div>
                        {{signupForm.username}}
                        <div class="nk-gap"></div>
                        {{signupForm.password}}
                    </div>
                        <button>Regístrame</button>
            </form>
```

El signup form es lo siguiente:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class signupForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=100, required=False, label=False, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'required':'true','name':'email','id':'email','class':'form-control','placeholder':'Email'}))
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False, label=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'required':'true','name':'username','id':'username','class':'required form-control','placeholder':'Usuario'}))
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False, label=False, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'required':'true','name':'password','id':'password','class':'required form-control','placeholder':'Contraseña'}))
```

Y mi vista es:

```
def signup(request):
  form = forms.signupForm(request.POST)
  if request.method == "POST":
    
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        email = form.cleaned_data("email")
        raw_password = form.cleaned_data("password")
        account = authenticate(email=email, password=raw_password)
        login(request, account)
        return HttpResponse("OK")
    else:
        print(form.errors)
        return HttpResponse("Ha habido un error")
elif request.method == "GET":
    return redirect("home")
```

¿Qué tengo que hacer para poder validar mi formulario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te comento que es lo que sucede, tu formulario signupForm esta heredando de la clase UserCreationForm y esta clase tiene 2 campos, password1 y password2, por eso te los pide lo puedes ver aqui: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm

Ahora como solución, puedes cambiar tu formulario de la siguiente manera:

```
class signupForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=100, required=False, label=False, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'required':'true','name':'email','id':'email','class':'form-control','placeholder':'Email'}))
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False, label=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'required':'true','name':'username','id':'username','class':'required form-control','placeholder':'Usuario'}))
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False, label=False, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'required':'true','name':'password','id':'password','class':'required form-control','placeholder':'Contraseña'}))
```

Cambiando el UserCreationForm por forms.Forms ya podrás acceder a los campos desde tu view, el detalle de usar el forms.Form es que necesitas escribir los métodos clean si requieres validar algún campo, y escribir el método save() si quieres crear algún registro en la base de datos.

Completo la respuesta, si quisieras escribir el metodo save() tendrias que tener algo así:

```
class signupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # Los campos van como required para que valide que no vayan vacios
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=100, required=True, label=False, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'required':'true','name':'email','id':'email','class':'form-control','placeholder':'Email'}))
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True, label=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'required':'true','name':'username','id':'username','class':'required form-control','placeholder':'Usuario'}))
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True, label=False, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'required':'true','name':'password','id':'password','class':'required form-control','placeholder':'Contraseña'}))

    def save(self, commit=True):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')

        if commit:
            # Se usa get_user_model() por si estas usando uno diferente al que viene por defecto en Django
            user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(username=username, password=password, email=email) # Esto crea el usuario y hashea el password
        return user
```

Comment: El problema es que si heredo de forms.Form no hereda el método save, ¿Cómo podría crearlo? Quiero que lo guarde en la tabla  users

Comment: Edite la respuesta para agregar esto que me comentas.